# "They've not" vs "They haven't"

Tags: word-usage, contractions

They both mean the same thing. Is there a preferred context for either of them, and which should be used in which type of situation?

Some examples:

"They've not left the plane."

"They haven't left the plane."

"I've not done that yet."

"I haven't done that yet."

Comment: Technically, they're both correct. Aesthetically, the latter sounds much better.

Comment: @Ricky - With respect, that's a matter of opinion. Both sound natural to me. There is no 'correct' situation in which to use either version.